# SD card commands for shutting down a SD card - like CMD15 or?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, sd-card

I am running an embedded Linux device and am I having trouble with file system corruptions during power off. We are talking about a normal Linux shutdown. It is one specific card I am having trouble with and it is only sometimes. I am trying to debug the Linux mmc device drives. Do anyone know what commands that should be send to the card when shutting down?
Maybe it is something like CMD15?

CMD15 does not seem to be used.

Comment: have you tested with different filesystem on SD card ?

Comment: Yes, I have 4 different card. 2 for same vendor and 2 for different vendors. 3 of the cards work just fine. The fourth is the one given problems. I need to find a SW solution for the problematic card.

Comment: can you try to umount the sd card before shutting down?

Comment: I am doing that already

Comment: by different filesystem I mean VFAT, EXT2 or other. If you will have still file system corruption (when other cards work fine) it may be problem with SDcard controller

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. I have corruption on VFAT and EXT3 and yes it all points toward the SDcard controller

Comment: Apparently you don't need a specific SD CMD sequence to shutdown the card